# Spring Boot - Moving a File in AWS from one service to another

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-sdk

I have 2 services A and B, and users can request to A the download of a file. For that, service A calls B asking for the file, gets it and sends a response to the users in form of a download.

The way I'm trying to do this is, service B gets the right call in the controller. Then it gets the `File` object from AWS and creates a `FileSystemResource` from it, returning back a `ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>`.

My problem is that when A receives the response, its body is null. The download still happens but I'm getting an empty file (zero bytes). Any idea what am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

My controller on service A

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> downloadDocument(
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse
) {
    httpServletResponse.setHeader(
            "Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=" + filename);

    httpServletResponse.setHeader(
            "Content-Type",
            "application/octet-stream"
    );

    return ResponseEntity.ok(
            documentsService.getDocumentToDownload(fileName));
}
```

My controller on service B

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> downloadDocument(
        @RequestParam(value = "fileName") String fileName,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse
) {
    File doc = documentsService.getFileForDocumentInS3(
            fileName);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(
            new FileSystemResource(doc.getAbsolutePath())
    );
}
```

This is what my service interacting with AWS does (on service B). Note that my `aws3Client` variable here is a wrapper that contains the transfer manager. Connectivity with AWS is good.

```
public File getFileForDocumentInS3(
        String bucketName,
        String fileKey
) {
    try {
        File toReturn = File.createTempFile(fileKey, ".tmp");
        toReturn.deleteOnExit();

        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileKey);

        awsS3Client.getTransferManager().download(getObjectRequest, toReturn);

        return toReturn;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //catching exception here
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing file size in serviceB.downloadDocument() or in getFileForDocumentInS3() methods just before these methods are returning anything.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Instead of passing the file between multiple services, use [Signed S3 URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html) and pass that back to the client where they can download the file directly.  Better performance and less bandwidth since the file is downloaded once directly.

Comment: @AmitKBist yes they do return a File that can be seen with the debugger and I see it points to the temp file created on my computer. If I open the file to see its content in a console I see data.

Comment: @KyleAnderson Thank you, I know, I was going to use the pre signed URLs because it just simplifies everything. But, one of my requirements is to be able to download different versions of the files (the bucket is versionable) and I couldn't find a way of creating a signed URL for the version file.

Comment: @KyleAnderson ok, so thanks to you I just noticed that the [GeneratePresignedUrlRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html#setVersionId-java.lang.String-) object does have a versionID that you can set. It just wasn't available in the version I was using. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you chose to send the files between the services because you couldn't generate signed URLs for specific versions of in a versioned bucket.

Since SDK version 1.11.123 (current latest is 1.11.186) you can set the version ID of a signed URL with [`GeneratedPresignedUrlRequest.withVersionId`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.html#withVersionId-java.lang.String-) like this:

```
final URL url = s3.generatePresignedUrl(
        new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("my-bucket", "my-key", HttpMethod.GET)
            .withVersionId("version-id")
);
```

Comment: Yep, you are right. I was using an old version of AWS and didn't check the API online... I updated to newer version and got that sorted.

Since you're the only one that posted an answer I'll mark it as the valid answer ;)

Comment: I saw after I posted the answer that you figured it out in the comments. In those cases you can answer your own question and accept that answer to help others in the future